# SSIS flat file source sql destination error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a csv file that has several fields, all of which are showing as:

```
Datatype - string [DT_STR]
OutputColumnWidth - 50
```

The mapping to my output SQL table is for fields that are all `varchar(50)`.

I'm on SQL Server 2012 and I'm using the SQL Server Native Client 11.0.

I'm getting the following truncation error:

```
Messages
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Description" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - myfilename_CSV.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Description]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - myfilename_CSV.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Description]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

How do I resolve this?

What I have tried is to set that column to in my source:

```
Datatype - string [DT_STR]
OutputColumnWidth - 200
```

And on my destination sql table I set it to varchar(200).

After I do that several other columns trigger the same error and I change the width on the source and destination as described above.

The package still fails.  Why isn't this working?

I've tried on SQL server 2012 and 2015.  I've used both the import wizard and and actual ssis package.

Answer (score 0):

As you are importing a flat file, there is no metadata to tell SSIS what data types are held within the file as you would get if you were importing from a database.

As such, you need to manually set your data types to match the data you are looking to import and build your table accordingly.

If, for example, your flat file contains:

- Col1 - String - Max length in file of 246 characters
- Col2 - Date - In format `yyyy-mm-dd`
- Col3 - String - Max length in file of 62 characters

You would need to set your connection manager to import as follows:

- Col1 - `string [DT_STR]` - Length at least 246
- Col2 - `Date [DT_DATE]`
- Col3 - `string [DT_STR]` - Length at least 62

You can't just take guesses at your data types or rely on SSIS to get them correct.  Actually understand your data and import it using the appropriate formats.

Comment: Makes sense. But my hang up is that I'm going back in to do this by: `[right click flat file source -> show advanced editor -> input and output properties -> flat file source output -> external columns / output columns]` I then change the quoted column to an appropriate data type.  However, this does not seem to work and gives: `the metadata of the following output columns does not match the meta data of the external columns with which the output columns are associated`. How do I go back and fix the dataypes/metadata of my source file columns and have it associated with my output?

Comment: Also note that I initially don't know what the appropriate size is for some of the DT_STR fields in my source.  So the table created by the oledb destination has the initial values from my source flat file (for example varchar(50)).  How does changing the metadata after the fact in my source propagate to the destination if the table has already been created when I initially set up the connection for my oledb destination?  Is the only way to fix this to know and appropriately setup all the source datatypes BEFORE mapping them to the destination?

Comment: @mo_maat  You need to change the data types in your Connection Manager and then make sure your Flat File Source matches them.  Double click on your Flat File Connection and in the Editor that pops up click `Advanced` on the left and edit the column data types in there.  Once done, open up your Flat File Source and refresh the metadata.  Regarding your second comment, either investigate your source or make your initial table in an environment where you can delete and recreate the table as required.